# Are these two different forms of the squeeze operator equivalent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information

As far as I know, the [squeeze operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_operator) can be presented as:
$$S(z) = \exp \left(\frac{1}{2}z a^\dagger a^\dagger-\frac{1}{2}z^* a a \right)$$
where $z=re^{i\theta}$.

When I tried to use Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula to expand $S(z)$, I found a paper [*"Impossibility of naively generalizing squeezed coherent states"*](http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1107) PRD 29, 1107(1984), where

$$
S'(z)
= \exp \left(
  \frac{1}{2} e^{i\theta} \tanh{r} a^\dagger a^\dagger
- \frac{1}{2} e^{-i\theta}\tanh{r} a a
+ (\text{sech} r-1)a^\dagger a - \frac{1}{2}\ln{(\cosh{r})}
\right) \, .
$$

I couldn't see they are equivalent to each other. I know that

$$\lim_{r->0} S'(z) = S(z),$$

but I don't think there is such assumption when we deal with most cases. Did I misunderstand something here?

Comment: Does this result from the action of the displacement operator $D(\alpha)~=~exp(\alpha a^\dagger - \alpha^*a)$ on the squeezed state operator $S(z)$? The BCH formula is usually applied to the multiplication of exponentiated operators.

Comment: @LawrenceB.Crowell I don't think so, there is no $\alpha$ in the second formula, and it is for squeezed vacuum state I think. There is a Zassenhaus formula for an expression like $exp(a+b)$, as I see from the BCH formula wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula.

Comment: You should revise your question, as it is misleading: S' and S are *not equal/equivalent*  to each other. The authors are magnificently obscure in their use of the normal-ordering operator *η* which means little to me, even giving them any benefit of the doubt. On the next page, they detail everything clearly, and show you how to easily go to (3.2) from S, via (3.7) and then (3.8). You'd be happiest ignoring (3.1) and its gonzo ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The usual decomposition is
$$
S(z)= \exp\left\{{\textstyle \frac12}(z {a^\dagger}^2 -z^* a^2)\right\}\\
=\exp\left\{e^{i\theta}{\textstyle \frac12}\tanh |z|\, {a^\dagger}^2\right\}\exp\left\{ -\ln\cosh |z| (a^\dagger  a+{\textstyle \frac12})\right\} \exp\left\{-e^{-i\theta}{\textstyle \frac12}\tanh |z| \, a^2\right\},\\
=\exp\left\{-e^{-i\theta}{\textstyle \frac12}\tanh |z| \,a^2\right\}\exp\left\{ +\ln\cosh |z| (a^\dagger a+\textstyle \frac12)\right\} \exp\left\{e^{i\theta}{\textstyle \frac12}\tanh |z|\, {a^\dagger}^2\right\}.
$$
This comes very quickly if you use from a Gaussian decomposition and the faithful, but non-unitary representation of the $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ algebra:
$$
a^2\mapsto 2i\sigma_-,\\
{a^\dagger}^2 \mapsto 2i\sigma_+,\\
(a^\dagger a+\textstyle \frac12)\mapsto \sigma_3.
$$
Your original paper has the key steps over the papge from the authors eq 3.1.
I can't see how the authors of your paper put all the exponentials together in their eq 3.1  though.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP appears to have decoupled, and so cannot fix the misleading question (searching for a proof of a non-fact), I'll answer @Emilio Pisanty's dare/call-of-the-bluff: this is a ritual confusion arising from that otherwise outstanding [Nieto et al. paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1107), probably in this site, as well. The [Truax paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.31.1988) cited in the OP's answer is a red herring--it does not address the essence of the OP's misreading of formula (3.1) in Nieto et al, and does not clarify anything already nicely and explicitly covered by Nieto et al. on p 1109. (At best, Truax is a footnote in R Gilmore's book detailing and explaining the technique.)

The standard result @mike stone reminds you of in his answer, (3.7) may be recast  through the magnificent CBH rearrangement (3.8) to *S(z)* =(3.2). (But note the obvious typo in the user right component of the last matrix of (3.5).)

Note (3.2) is in normal order, i.e. correct and complete without any commutators having been sacrificed in any normal-ordering truncation whatsoever!

From (3.2), one then may work backwards to the *completely superfluous* (! yes, I'll stick my neck out) (3.1), correctly copied as
$$
S(z)=\eta S'(z)  \\
= \eta \exp \left(
  \frac{1}{2} e^{i\theta} \tanh{r} a^\dagger a^\dagger
- \frac{1}{2} e^{-i\theta}\tanh{r} a a
+ (\text{sech} r-1)a^\dagger a - \frac{1}{2}\ln{(\cosh{r})}
\right)  ,
$$
where $\eta$ is the ***normal ordering operator***, trivializing any and all commutators in its argument, so, then,  dictating  dealing with noncommuting operators as commutative symbols when inside its domain. It is an empty and inessential flourish, unfamiliar to lots of non-QFT students, and adding little (nothing?) to the discussion. A good referee would have advised the authors to skip  superfluous asides such as this to enhance readability. This very question is proof of his hypothetical sagacity, had he acted.  So the question is a distraction/misreading of a classic and  important group-theoretical technique. (E.g., I'm using it [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/312818/66086).)

Answer (score -1):

The eq. (23a) in paper *"Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff relations and unitarity of SU(2) and SU(1,1) squeeze operators"* (PRD 31, 8) solves my question. Detailed proof are shown in this paper.

Comment: This is a bit short for this site, and it will be of limited usefulness to future visitors with similar questions. Please include a summary of the resolution to your problem here.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Sorry, I'm not going to paste the whole paper here, since the paper is basically about the derivation of my question. I'm answering my own question because it might be helpful to others too. I can delete the question if it doesn't satisfy the rule for this site.

Comment: `@`LuZhang That's not what I meant - the emphasis is on summary. You don't need to (and shouldn't) paste the full paper, but a paragraph detailing the key points would vastly improve this answer.