# Can I create squeezing with a $P^2$ interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics, squeezed-states

One approach to squeeze light is through the one-mode squeezing operator, which can be written as $e^{-i H t}$ with $H \sim (a^2 - (a^\dagger)^2)$. My question is, can I create squeezing with $H \sim P^2 \sim (a-a^\dagger)^2$ ?

Is this described anywhere in the literature? I know it might not be easy to implement, and so of limited relevance. The term $P^2$ has also additional terms in the expansion $\sim a^\dagger a$, which I'm not sure how they contribute.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably messy to implement in Fock space (number states), but can be related to the conventional squeeze operator through the methods of Nieto et al. discussed in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305963/are-these-two-different-forms-of-the-squeeze-operator-equivalent), in an elaborate CBH rebraiding.

In Hilbert space, however, it is elementary, if not trivial. Let us discuss the effect of the operator $\hat S'=e^{-3\hat p^2/2}$ on a plain Gaussian state centered at the origin in both coordinate and momentum space! Nondimensionalize $\hbar,\omega,m$ by absorbing them in your units, so they are set equal to one, for simplicity; they can be reinstated at will.

You have, then,
$$
\langle x|\psi\rangle = \psi(x) = \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} e^{-x^2/2} ={1\over \sqrt{2\pi}}\int dp e^{ipx}\phi(p)~~\leadsto \\
\phi(p)=\langle p|\psi\rangle =\frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} e^{-p^2/2} , \Longrightarrow \\
\langle \hat x\rangle = \langle \hat p\rangle=0, ~~~ \langle \hat x^2\rangle = \langle \hat p^2\rangle =1/2 ~~~,
$$
hence it saturates the standard Heisenberg uncertainty relation (Kennard),
$$
\Delta x = 1/\sqrt{2} , ~~~ \Delta p = 1/\sqrt{2} ~~~\leadsto \Delta x\Delta p =1/2.
$$

Now consider the un-normalized state
$$ 
\hat S'|\psi\rangle \equiv | \psi'\rangle \leadsto \\
\phi'(p)\propto \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} e^{-3p^2/2}   e^{-p^2/2} =\frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} e^{-2p^2} ~~~~\leadsto \psi'(x) \propto \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} e^{-x^2/8} ~~\Longrightarrow \\
\Delta x =  \sqrt{2} , ~~~ \Delta p = 1/(2\sqrt{2}) ~~~\leadsto \Delta x\Delta p =1/2.
$$
(The primed states need their normalization adjusted, but it washes out in the uncertainty relation!)
The new state is *also* a Gaussian, still saturating the uncertainty  relation as before, even as the width of the *x*-distribution has expanded by a factor of two, while the *p*-distribution has been squeezed to half its original width.

The operator $\hat S '$ has squeezed your (coherent) state. In the language of [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezed_coherent_state#Operator_representation), $e^{\zeta}=1/2$.